# Magento 2 system xml config get groups name programtically

Tags: magento2.2.2, system.xml, system-config

I have a custom phtml file in system config and been added to 3 groups:

`group_1`, `group_2`, `group_3`

in phtml I have:

```
<input id="my_value" type="number" name="groups[group_1][groups][my_settings][fields][my_value][value]" value="<?= $block->getValue('my_value'); ?>"/>
```

Where name=group[group_1] should be dinamically depending on which group it it belongs: for example: 
`groups[<?= $GROUP ?>][groups][my_settings][fields][my_value][value]`

Where `$GROUP` will hold value for each group:

It works if I hard coded for one for group e.g: `groups[group_1]`

How can I get groups `name` programatically?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what the config screen looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find out by simply using `$element->getName()` in render:

```
public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        //print_r($element->getName());//this will print full path on every group correctly.
        $this->_pathGroupName = $element->getName(); 
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

public function getPath() {
        return $this->_pathGroupName;
    }
```

In my phtml:

```
...    
<input id="<= $key ?>" type="number" value="<?= $block->getValue() ?>" name="<?= $block->getPath();?>" /> 
...
```

I then ended up with in my inputs like:

```
<input id="0" type="number" name="groups[group_1][groups][my_settings][fields][my_value][value]" value="<?= $block->getValue('my_value'); ?>"/>

<input id="1" type="number" name="groups[group_2][groups][my_settings][fields][my_value][value]" value="<?= $block->getValue('my_value'); ?>"/>

<input id="2" type="number" name="groups[group_3][groups][my_settings][fields][my_value][value]" value="<?= $block->getValue('my_value'); ?>"/>
```